# phpstorm or netbeans copy file to different directory after commit

Tags: svn, netbeans, ssh, commit, phpstorm

Hi, here is my situation:

I am working on a large website. It was originally created without version control. There is now a repository, but due to reasons out of my control, the page has not been converted into a repository, rather, all of the files I might want to edit have been copied into a repository. It does not contain the entire site, so it is not functional on its own.

So the current set up is that after I commit the file in my IDE, I have to log in to the server over SSH, then cp the file from the subversion directory to the web directory.

So my question is: Is there any way to automatically copy the file to the web directory after it has been committed to the repository? This is the DEV environment for the web page, so there is not danger of accidentally overwriting something important. A solution in Netbeans, PHPStorm, and/or in the command shell itself would be much appreciated.

My server is running on CentOS and I have root access via Putty in windows. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for hooks and i recommend you read this article:

http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook

then try to fix the situation by throwing everything on that site into the repo.